# IE7 changes my navigation position, after the anchor is clicked

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, css-position

I have navigation which is positioned absolutely to it's relative parent. I've used hacks to position it correctly in IE7 and IE8. It's ok, more or less in comparison to what I have used (CSS3) for FF/Chrome and Opera. My problem is that, while the anchor is clicked in the menu, whole navigation box is moved to the left. Here's the link to the website. 
[Link](http://man-of-the-north.pl/lab/tomtrans.eu)

Everything works fine in IE8, but that IE7 is driving me crazy.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I forgot to mention, that if you want to see the bug open the link in IE7, or IE9 with view set to IE7.

Answer (score 0):

OK the problem's solved. I changed some properties of IE7 CSS hack: position to "relative", and float to "right".